# Azure AD/on-prem AD Hybrid user cannot change password wont stay enabled

Tags: active-directory, entra-id

Just setup Azure connect and noticed that some, not all users imported from the selected OU that when setup had the check for "user cannot change password" enabled per company policy(not my choice) and after the first sync the check was removed. I checked the box again for user cannot change password on the two accounts and when it sync'd again the box got unchecked again. I tried searching with a few different phrases, but did not find anything useful. I have a guess based on their level of access, but would like to know for sure since this is the beginning of the move to the cloud.

Comment: Open a support case with Office 365 from your tenant. It's free and they'll help you resolve the issue.

Comment: As long as you use password writeback and allow users to change their password in m365, the flag will be ovberwritten.